# assembly scanf in loop doesn't loop

Tags: assembly, infinite-loop, scanf, strcmp

I'm trying to write a piece of code in assembly that takes an input and if the input matches a given value it jumps to another instruction. However this get's stuck in an infite loop if the input isn't the same as the $attack string does anybody know why?

```
_takeaction: 
    movl $-400,%eax         #\
    addl %ebp,%eax          #-give adress -400(%ebp) to scanf
    push %eax               #/ 
    push $action            #ask for action
    call _scanf             #scan data
    push -400(%ebp)         
    push $attack            
    call _strcmp            
    cmp $0, %eax            
    je _attack 
    movl $1,%eax 
    push -400(%ebp)
    push $run
    call _strcmp
    cmp $0, %eax 
    je _run 

jmp _takeaction
```

....code that's never reached .....

```
_attack : 
        movl -8(%ebp) , %eax # store player attack in eax 
        subl %eax , -208(%ebp)
        jmp _actiontaken

_run : 
        push -216(%ebp)
        call _printf
        jmp _actiontaken
```

Could it have something to do with the fflush function?

Comment: How did you decide to use `-400(%ebp)` as a buffer? Where is `ebp` pointing to?

Comment: %ebp is set at the beginning of the program to the esp the 400 comes from the fact that I want to be able to store up to 100 variables as the code expandes currently little of these variables are filled.

Comment: Did you actually reserve that space by moving `esp`? (keep in mind that the stack grows downward). Also, why not declare variables that you can give meaningful names instead of using cryptic addresses like `-###(%ebp)`?

Comment: Yes I did the first thing I do is addl $8,%esp

Comment: Since the stack grows downward you should _subtract from_ `esp` to reserve space on the stack.